# startActivity on "file://" links crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I am trying to create program that simply opens file on sdcard. I tried opening mp3, mp4, and apk - the code bellow always crashes unexpectedly.

```
  String _path = "file:///sdcard/1.apk";

     Uri outputFileUri = Uri.parse(_path);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Market links also crashes. But when I set _path="http://google.com" - browser opens normally. How can I make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to install the apk, you need to use the following:

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/1.apk";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

If you're trying to launch the app (after installing), then:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.pkg.addr", "com.pkg.addr.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

If you're trying to launch a player to play the mp3 file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/1.mp3");
intent.setDataAndType(data,"audio/mp3");
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great! Works! Thanks!

So I need always to define mime-type? Don't android let user to choose what he want to do with the file?

Comment: Android does let the user choose which application should handle the file, among those applications on his phone that are capable of handling it.

Comment: But when I don't set Type, application crashes. Why android not showing standart openfile dialog when type not set?

Comment: This code works only in test class that extends activity. I have a class that extends ListActivity. When I try to inherit class Activity, to launch startActivity, I got crash again. This how I inherit: Activity activity = new Activity();   Then I launch intent with activity activity.startActivity(intent); it crashes.

Comment: You should not instantiate an `Activity` using `new`. Since you're new to Android, I would suggest you read up on some of the [dev guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) and take a look at sample programs.

Comment: I could not find how to properly intilialize Activity class in the android dev. Could you please tell me, and I will understand it with the help of example. As I partly understood somehow I should set context to the class. Thanks!

Comment: found solution. I should use context.startactivity()